# Recover Google Cloud Shell Home Directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

My G Suite user which I log into GCP with has been renamed from *firstname*@domain.com to *firstname.lastname*@domain.com

I have now logged back into Cloud Shell and my home directory content is gone.

Is there any way of recovering this?

Thanks

Comment: Doubtful. It's all temporary anyway; you shouldn't have anything imporatnt there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Everything stored in $HOME is persistent. If you do not access Cloud Shell regularly, the $HOME directory persistent storage may be recycled. You will receive an email notification before this occurs. Starting a Cloud Shell session will prevent its removal.

Comment: Go the Google Console -> IAM. Is the old user name still there? If yes, create a G Suite user with the old name, login and check if your data is still there. If no, contact Google Support.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, that qualifies as persistent (and not ephemeral), but it is still temporary. Similar to `/tmp` versus `/var/tmp` on a Linux system; the former is ephemeral and erased on every reboot; the latter is persistent, but may be erased at any time (usually it's set up so that old files are deleted). Both are still temporary. I have no reason to trust that persistent temporary space won't be erased while I'm not looking, even if it isn't supposed to be...

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Good explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley I tried creating a user with the old name but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, you have some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) when working with the shell, as stated before you shouldn't have important information stored over there and should be moved to Google Cloud Storage if needed.

There's no way to restore the data lost once your profile was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if your G Suite address has been renamed, your `$HOME` directory in the Cloud Shell changes. The old one is still there though.

1. Log into your Cloud Shell
2. Type `cd ..`
3. Type `ls`

Your previous `$HOME` directory should pop up. The shell is linux based, so it uses the same user logic. The thing is that the LDAP is automatically chosen based on your user account LDAP.